# Ubuntu, Mercurial unable to commit

Tags: software-installation, netbeans, mercurial

I'm trying to commit from Netbeans to a mercurial repository. Did all the SSH setup but get the following error:

```
Mercurial Commit
----------------
Disable description field.
ERROR Command failed:
Command: [hg, commit, --repository, /media/javier/Development/NetBeans/jWrestling, --cwd, /media/javier/Development/NetBeans/jWrestling, --user, Javier Ortiz Bultron <javier.ortiz.78@gmail.com>, --logfile, /tmp/hgcommit2826840947170512752.hgm, jWrestling-Client/Client/UI/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/javydreamercsw/ui/wizard/wrestler/FeatPanelUI.form, jWrestling-Client/Client/UI/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/javydreamercsw/ui/wizard/wrestler/FeatPanelUI.java]
Output: [abort: Function not implemented: '/media/javier/Development/NetBeans/jWrestling/.hg/store/journal']
INFO: End of Commit
```

Not even sure what else to say about it, I'm kind of lost on this one. I get the same type of error if I try from the terminal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you initialize that directory as a mercurial repository?

Comment: Yes, operations like update work fine. This was an existing project I worked with on the USB on Windows.

Comment: Perhaps it is a slightly older archive format and needs to be upgraded first, as it seems the version of hg on Ubuntu is trying to perform an action the repository doesn't support.

Comment: How can I check that then?

Comment: I don't know. It was just a semi-educated guess based on the "Function not implemented" error. Perhaps it would be best to move this instead to general StackExchange, as it seems more like a mercurial issue and isn't likely specific to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reporting the issue to the TortoiseHg bug tracker finally the root cause was found. Basically I had this repository in a USB drive formatted as exFAT that doesn't seem to allow some operations Tortoise needs to do. See here for details: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/4179/function-not-implemented

Basically using the repository from Desktop works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to make it work after installing as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mercurial tortoisehg
```

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627414/correct-way-to-install-mercurial-on-ubuntu

Comment: Still not working. :(